# How can I push a JSON to firebase realtime database from cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So I am very new to Firebase and also this is the first time I use TypeScript (no JavaScript experience either), and here is what I try to do. I have a JSON structure that I want my cloud function to add to database every time some action happens. My question is the following - could you point me to the right direction, on where I can get info besides official documentation, maybe some code examples would be great. Here is the JSON format I want to push to database. I want this to appear just like Firebase structures data in the console, nested nodes etc.

```
{
  'Player': { 
    'id':'name',
    'visible': {
      'place': 'a1',
      'sign': 'rock'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cloud function, you can use code like this to update the database:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

// In your function
//##########################################
var playerRef = admin.database().ref('/Player');

// You can group multiple updates in an object
var updates = {};
updates['id'] = 'name';
updates['visible'] = {
  place: 'a1',
  sign: 'rock'
};

// Make sure to return the promise
return playerRef.update(updates);
//##########################################
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much, and also wanted to ask - could you point me to the direction of any type of literature that could clearify more my understanding?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, check out the [official code sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js) and also the documentation for the [admin database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)